# A method for creating a display that shows information located in the first linked XML file in an ATOM feed

Tags: rss, atom-feed

I'm a fair novice when it comes to this stuff but I like to create little projects to help me learn. Normally I am able to google-fu my way around a project but in this instance but I've hit a wall.

I'm trying to create an Atom/RSS feed display (to output to a Screen via a Raspberry Pi) using the UK's House of Parliament's vote feed found here (http://api.data.parliament.uk/resources/files/feed?dataset=9&filetype=xml). However, the Feed links to separate XML files which contain the information I want displayed. Most RSS feed displays use the information direct from the feed.

So what I'm asking, is there any existing code libraries or similar, or can someone point out a methodology to get my Raspberry Pi to:

1. Go to the Atom feed and get the latest link.
2. Look into the newest file and grab the Division Title, AyeCount, & NoCount data.
3. Print these to screen.

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: "is there any existing code libraries or similar" — Library recommendation questions are off-topic.

Comment: "can someone point out a methodology" — The three step plan you have there looks like a perfectly reasonable methodology.